# REGEXP_LIKE strange behavior

Tags: regex, oracle

I started doing a bit of research on `REGEXP_LIKE` function and here is what I found on oracle website:

> REGEXP_LIKE is similar to the LIKE condition, except REGEXP_LIKE performs regular >expression matching instead of the simple pattern matching performed by LIKE'

So, I tried to compare the two:

1) In `LIKE` case, we have `%` and `_` at our disposal;

So, I run:

```
SELECT 'true' 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE 'true' like '%ru_';
```

I would get 'true' in the output as expected;

2) in REGEXP case if I run:

```
SELECT 'true' 
  FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('true', '[[:alpha:]]');
```

or

```
SELECT 'true' 
  FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('true', 'u');
```

I would get "true" in result set in either case. I would expect `regexp_like` to match the entire string according to regexp, instead it matches only one character in given example;

I would also expect taken for example

```
SELECT 'true' 
  FROM dual WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('true', '[[:alpha:]]');
```

to be

```
SELECT 'true' 
  FROM dual 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('true', '[[:alpha:]]+');
```

which means that `[[:alpha:]]` token can be applied multiple times which will make true to be matched against reg exp. Without `+` or `*`, `[[:alpha:]]` token would only match one character only which is "t" and since only one match is required, it won't match any more characters failing the match.

To me it's a strange behavior. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. thanks.

*EDIT:* Additional notes:

Why I started looking into it in the first place is the questions of ensuring that first name doesn't contain any numbers but just letters and practice exam would give the following answers:
A.

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS ADD CONSTRAINT cust_f_name CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(cust_first_name, '^A-Z'))NOVALIDATE;
```

B.

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS ADD CONSTRAINT cust_f_name CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(cust_first_name, '^[0-9]'))NOVALIDATE;
```

C.

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS ADD CONSTRAINT cust_f_name CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(cust_first_name, '[[:alpha:]]'))NOVALIDATE;
```

D.

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS ADD CONSTRAINT cust_f_name CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(cust_first_name, '[[:digit:]]'))NOVALIDATE;
```

They list C as correct but none of them are correct.

looks like the correct might be the following according to the answer below: '^[[:alpha:]]+$'

Comment: I don't really understand your question, are you asking why isn't it behaving like this regexp `'^u$'` (which means the exact string 'u') ?

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand your question, but regexp_like will evaluate to true if the match is not empty try this query to see the difference `SELECT REGEXP_substr('true', '^u$'), REGEXP_substr('true', 'u')
  FROM dual;`

Comment: I agree with you. None of the answers is correct. The correct regex, as you said, should be '^[[:alpha:]]+$'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex comparison is true if the pattern matches *any part* of the value.

If you want to enforce a match to the *whole* value, add `^` and `$` to the start/end of the pattern:

```
SELECT 'true' 
FROM dual 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('true', '^[[:alpha:]]{4}$')
```

Comment: A.B.Cade and Bohemian, this is it, you folks pushed me into the right direction of analysis of regexp. It does make sense now.